# Button doesn't work with .pull-left (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

My buttons don't work when I put `.pull-left`. I tried using the W3C validator on the document, but no problem detected.

[Here's the code.](http://tpg.nicolapps.ch/button.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've made .secondline display as block and are positioning it, it's "covering up" the button.

You can keep it block level, but instead of positioning along an axis, try positioning with line-height.

```
.secondline {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

However, I think it's a better end result to use the grid system for this. Below is an example of what you could do using the content from your first result. (Of course, you would need to add your code and content)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    V ➜ GARE CORNAVIN  (21:44)  
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    Button  
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
    19 minutes
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. The best way you can thank me is by marking the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with HTML structure issue rather than a Bootstrap issue. One of your HTML elements appears to be covering the button. It appears as though it's your "time" span. I would recommend trying to restructure your HTML with your button in a div class and the minutes in another div class. You have a lot of span elements there that could probably be eliminated to simplify your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to increase the z-index of the covered element, your code is no longer linked but try adding style="z-index:2147483647" to the parent of the element with .pull-left